# changing the time format from HH:MM:SS to HH:MM AM/PM

Tags: php, mysql, time, format

I made a table in mysql and inside the table there is a column which its type is `TIME`.

the value inside the column is `10:20:00` ,

and I want to know how to convert it to hour: minute format  such as `10:20 AM` when I fetch it in php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('10:20:00', '%h:%i %p')
```

[**Here is the SQLFiddel Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19572)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
echo $time = date("g:i A", strtotime("10:20:00"));
//output : 10:20 AM
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was searching for the code for 2 hours, in around 100s websites.  You saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`echo date("H:i p", strtotime("10:20:00"));`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AMR Thanks for you advice, i'll sleep much better now. Phew!

Comment: I am happy I could facilitate!

Answer (score 0):

If you which to do so in PHP, create a new instance of `DateTime` and pass in the time string to it's constructor.

```
$time = new DateTime($mysqlTimeString);
echo $time->format('h:i A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
SELECT 
TIME_FORMAT(field_name,"%h:%i %p") as time 
from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TIME_FORMAT()` of mysql to change time format.

e.g,

```
TIME_FORMAT(yourValue, timeFormat);
TIME_FORMAT('12:20:00', '%h:%i %p');
```