# List data of 24hours format ( H:i ) data stored in database into 12hours format (AM and PM both)

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I want to list the data coming from the database into 12hours format. But I don't actually find a way to do it.

What I tried is :

```
SELECT count(gr.GeneralReportId) as netcount, TIME_FORMAT(gr.TimeOfAcc,'%H') as hour
        from generalreport gr
        GROUP BY hour ASC
```

I tried replacing %H with %h, but it provides the net count only in one of the 12hours. But I want to retreive the data in both the 12hours format ( AM and PM both ).

**Column format (H:i):**

[image]

**Output currently received with %h :**

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Its mysql and I have updated it. Thank you for the quick response

Comment: You can add `%p` to your format to include the AM or PM marker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing the time format from HH:MM:SS to HH:MM AM/PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635526/changing-the-time-format-from-hhmmss-to-hhmm-am-pm)

Comment: Using `%r` is also an option, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @Luuk already tried this. It doesnot fulfill the requirement.

Comment: When doing `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(now(),'%r')`, i do get `01:02:27 PM` which seems to be in 12 hour format with `PM` added .....  (localtime is 13:02)

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Was this thing just to downvote? Since everyone has understood the point of the question leaving you.
And what do you suppose me to add rather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want AM/PM, you need to include that in the format:

```
TIME_FORMAT(gr.TimeOfAcc, '%h %p')
```

I recommend using `'%H'`, because 24 hour clocks are correctly ordered with `order by <expression>`.

If you want to order by the column after an aggregation, use:

ORDER BY MIN(gr.TimeOfAcc)

Comment: I tried your approach but only the half daytime was correctly published. The other half is like 13PM 14PM 15PM and more importantly it is giving the output from 00AM to 24PM

Comment: @MeerajAdhikari . . . That is a lower-case `h`:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=933b72a3ad858e7dbf070586d4930002.

Comment: Thank you @Linoff. It solved the half of the issue. But it doesnot order the format clockwise. Rather it is 01AM 01PM 02AM 02PM..
Any solution for it ?
I could mark your reply as answer